# Find the value of $\theta$?

Tags: trigonometry

An operation maps the point $(x, y)$ on to the point $(x cos \theta, y sin \theta)$.

i) Find the value of $\theta$ for which the y-axis is the image of the line $y = x$.

ii) Draw a diagram to show the locus of the image of the point $(2, 2)$ as $\theta$ increases from $0^\circ$ to $90^\circ$.

Comment: The first one is asking you to find $\theta$ such that $$\{(x\cos(\theta), y\sin(\theta))\colon (x,y)\in \mathbb R^2\}=\{(0,x)\colon x\in \mathbb R\}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: What is the graph of $x = a \cos t, y = a \sin t$?

Comment: Sounds like a circular argument (joke).